# Is it possible to exit a generator?

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

Consider the following:

```
list = [1,3..]

generate n = [compute y | y <- list , (compute y) < n ] 

compute a = ... whatever ...
```

Is it possible to exit the generator before getting to the last element of my list 
(e.g. if (compute y > 20)?
I want to save computing power. I only need the elements smaller than n.

I'm new to Haskell. A simple answer might be the best answer.

Answer (score 8):

The wonderful thing about Haskell is that it's lazy.  If you said

```
> let x = generate 100000
```

then Haskell doesn't immediately calculate `generate 100000`, it just creates a promise to start calculating it (we normally call this a thunk).

If you want only elements only until `compute y > 20`, then you can do

```
> takeWhile (<= 20) (generate 100000)
```

This is the same semantics that let you do something like

```
> let nums = [1..] :: [Integer]
```

This makes a lazy reference to all Integer values from 1 to infinity.  You can then do things like

```
> take 10 $ map (* 10) $ drop 12345 $ map (\x -> x ^ 2 + x ^ 3 + x ^ 4) $ filter even nums
[3717428823832552480,3718633373599415160,3719838216073150080,3721043351301172120,3722248779330900000,3723454500209756280,3724660513985167360,3725866820704563480,3727073420415378720,3728280313165051000]
```

And while tihs seems like a lot of work, it only calculates the bare minimum necessary to return the 10 elements you requested.  The argument to `take 10` in this example is still an infinite list, where we first grabbed all the evens, then mapped an algebraic expression to it, then dropped the first 12345 elements, then multiplied all remaining (infinite) elements by 10.  Working with infinite structures in Haskell is very common and often advantageous.

As a side note, your current definition of `generate` will do extra work, you'd want something more like

```
generate n = [compute_y | y <- list, let compute_y = compute y, compute_y < n]
```

This way `compute y` is only calculated once and the value is shared between your filter `compute_y < n` and the left hand side of the `|` in the comprehension.  Also be aware that when you have a condition in a comprehension, this gets translated to a `filter`, not a `takeWhile`:

```
> -- filter applies the predicate to all elements in the list
> filter (\x -> x `mod` 5 == 0) [5,10,15,21,25]
[5,10,15,20]
> -- takeWhile pulls values until the predicate returns False
> takeWhile (\x -> x `mod` 5 == 0) [5,10,15,21,25]
[5,10,15]
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried to use takeWhile and it works pretty well. But I have a problem with understanding a problem that occurred.                              perfect n = takeWhile (<=n) ([y | y <- [6,8..], sum (factors y) == y])
factors z = [f | f <- [1..z-1], mod z f == 0]                                                                         Putting in perfect 495 : done in sth like 0.001s  but with 496 it takes up to 10-15 seconds and I don't know why.